# How to Show Dynamic Data in LazyList or Universal Image Loader?

Tags: android, json, lazy-loading, universal-image-loader

I'm testing both [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) (LL) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) (UIL) that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview). Also I have successfully made some modifications to retrieve the URL's to load from a JSON document. The [JSON](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json) is from Flickr. I got the *url* (for obtain photos) and more data like *title*, *description* and *author* from JSON. Before using these image loading tools I passed data to the view with a SimpleAdapter like this:

```
    // Hashmap for ListView        
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Then some code to put JSON DATA into itemsList, then

```
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, itemsList,
            R.layout.item,
            new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_AUTHOR }, new int[] {
                    R.id.title, R.id.description, R.id.author });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView list = getListView();


    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();
            String author = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
            in.putExtra(TAG_AUTHOR, author);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

Following this [guide](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). Now that I tried to merged my code with LL or UIL I can't make it work.

Those image loaders uses their own adapter with a GetWiew method. So finally here's the question:
**How do I pass my own dynamic data to their adapters?**

---

To make it more clear, I want to show info like *title*, *description* and *author* at the right side of the photo instead of "item X" from picture bellow:

[image: Example from LazyList]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom adapter:

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private List<String> mImageUrls;

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, List<String> imageUrls, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        mImageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mImageUrls.get(position), imageView);

        return view;
    }
}
```

And pass `imageUrls` to constructor.

Comment: That would work. I took a different approach on the problem. Anyway, thanks you!